# How to open .8 file with man?

Tags: manpage

How do I properly open a local `.8` file like `named.8` with the `man` command?

I have the `man` command and I have a `.8` file. In my case it is `bind9/bin/named/named.8` (which can be found on github) I'm pretty sure that I was able to do it before.

In my specific case, it is

```
$ man --version
man 2.7.5

$ man -C named.8
man: can't parse directory list `.\" Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2003-2009, 2011, 2013-2017 Internet Systems Consortium, Inc. ("ISC")
'
man: can't make sense of the manpath configuration file /etc/manpath.config
```

`named.8` starts with:

```
.\" Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2003-2009, 2011, 2013-2017 Internet Systems Consortium, Inc. ("ISC")
.\" 
.\" This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
.\" License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
.\" file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
.\"
.hy 0
.ad l
'\" t
.\"     Title: named
.\"    Author: 
.\" Generator: DocBook XSL Stylesheets v1.78.1 <http://docbook.sf.net/>
.\"      Date: 2014-02-19
.\"    Manual: BIND9
```

I tried Google searching "How to open a .8 file." and there were 0 results, so I think there should be a result for this (which is n times better of a reason to ask the question than if I only needed to know the answer for myself where n is the number of future searches for that made by anyone.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`man ./named.8` will work. `man` will take a filename as an argument, but if the argument "looks like" the name of a manpage, it will assume that it is, and not check for a file of that name. By adding `./` to refer to a file in the current directory, you make it clear that it's a filename, and so `man` will treat it as such. You could also use a full absolute path.

Comment: This is good. So good that it's bad. Now I don't know whether to choose your answer or `Lok Lam Cheng`'s answer.

Comment: @TimothySwan doesn't bother me one way or the other. `-l` looks like a good choice. But it's worth knowing for lots of things that try to guess whether something is a filename or not, that a `./` can help you out. e.g. if you have a file named `-x` and something insists on thinking it's a flag because it starts with `-`, well, call it `./-x` and it doesn't start with `-` anymore.

Comment: @TimothySwan: FWIW, @hobbs' answer works in `macos`, whereas the other answer (using the `-l` argument) does not.

Comment: @Seamus is correct, macOS has an ancient BSD `man` with no `-l` option. There are two options I can think of there: (A) You can run `nroff -man <filename>|less`, which will run the file through the same preprocessor `man` uses to format the output. (B) Or, more stupidly, _if the file is in the proper section subdirectory_ (like, `man1` for `foo.1`, `man8` for your `named.8` file, etc.), you can run `man -M <parent_dir> <pagename>`, and it will use the directory you specify as the manpath, finding e.g. `man8/named.8` at that path and displaying it. (Like I said, stupid.)

Answer (score 19):

You can open a local file `named.8` using the following command:
`man -l named.8`

Reference:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html

Comment: Yes. `Activate "local" mode.  Format and display local manual files instead of searching through the system's manual  collection.` Derp. But you must admit the `man page` for `man` is brimming.

Answer (score 8):

The `.8` part of the page name is indicating it's in section 8 of the man pages.  Section `#8` is the manpage section that is specific to System administration commands... usually commands own or controlled by root.

The command `man` will load that page as long as it in a proper manpath.  For Ubuntu, this path is configured in `/etc/manpath.config`.

You will find `/usr/share/man` as one of the manpath locations.  If you put that file (named.8) in the `/usr/share/man/man8` section it can be loaded with the command:

```
$ man named
```

This is assuming the file is located:

```
/usr/share/man/man8/named.8
```

You can be more specific in loading that section with this command (which will load the same page:

```
$ man 8 named
```

You can see other examples of the structure by exploring the various man pages that have automatically been placed in the `/usr/share/man` directory hierarchy.

If you properly compile and install the github package, it will place the manual in one of the manpath locations and be loaded with one of these two commands:

```
$ man named
$ man 8 named
```

The second of the two commands are specifying (as your question asks) **how to open a.8** file.

Of course, you can get lots of other details about the man page commands and structure with the commands:

```
$ man man
$ man manpath
```

Each one of the document pages will have links at the bottom to explain in more details other related commands, of which you can followup with:

```
$ man [name of other references in the page]
```

**Other ways of calling man pages/man files include:**

You can also open any man page by specifying the direct namepath of the page.  For instance:

```
$ man /usr/share/man/man8/named.8
$ man ./named.8
```

Since **named.8** doesn't exist in a default ubuntu install, you can test this option on a page that actually exist (`/usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz`):

```
$ man /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
$ man ./apt.8gz
```

When opening a page directly, rather than a page in the manpath, but keep in mind that if you are in the same folder as the page you would have to use `man ./manpagename.8`, whereas `man manpagename.8` will search the manpath.  It wouldn't see it, just as trying to call an execute file wouldn't see the command in the current directory unless that current directory was in the search path.

**Note**

Related to your Google search for the `.8` extension, your hits would have been more specific to your question had you put quotes (") around the ".8" part of the question.  Since it was a man page you were working with including the word **man** in the filter would have been even better.

This formatted question may help the next time you perform a Google search:

[how to open a ".8" man file](https://www.google.com/search?ei=qT3TWvukE7LJ5gKMsrSAAQ&q=how+to+open+a+%22.8%22+man+file&oq=how+to+open+a+%22.8%22+man+file&gs_l=psy-ab.3...452421.453878.0.459174.4.4.0.0.0.0.268.643.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.521...0i8i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.GgPuM5sKCqw)

Or, using the same search filter you put for your AU question:

[How to open ".8" file with man?](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Y0DTWp71MeWH5wL-6aCQBw&q=How+to+open+%22.8%22+file+with+man%3F&oq=How+to+open+%22.8%22+file+with+man%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.152476.155050.0.155724.2.2.0.0.0.0.245.364.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.118....0.otEHPHqUXEc)

Comment: What an... incredibly long answer that does, eventually, get around to answering the question asked, but does it in such a roundabout, irrelevancy-filled fashion that it's easy to miss the useful answer as it gets lost amid all the noise. This answer would be good, if it were about 60%-80% shorter.

Answer (score 2):

While other answers are correct, for many files you can try a generic solution: as long as you have `lesspipe` installed and activated you can do:

```
less some_file.8
```

and get a formatted output. If you have `lesspipe` installed, but not activated for some reason, you'll have to run `eval $(lesspipe.sh)` first.